# RequireJS - Issues properly loading ko.editables.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, requirejs

Im new to requirejs and loving it so far. I have it working juste fine with knockout js. I then introduced a plugins called ko.editables (https://github.com/romanych/ko.editables) that would allow to undo changes very easily.

I added the path on in my equirejs config file so that ko.editables has knockout as it's dependency. In my knockout application code I defined knockout and then ko.editables and the files (knockout.js and ko.editables.js) are loading correctly from what I can see in my crome console sources.

Here is my requirejs config file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './js',
    paths: {
        "ko_editables": "ko.editables"
    },
        "shim": {
        ko_editables: {
            deps : [ 'knockout' ]
        }
    }
});
```

This is my application code I have that controls my knockout view model.

```
    define(["knockout", "ko_editables"], function(ko, editables) {

... I hide some code here just to show the ko.editable functions im using.

    self.Edit = function (incident) {
        var CurrentEdititngIncident = self.EditingIncident();
        if (CurrentEdititngIncident && CurrentEdititngIncident != incident) {
            if (CurrentEdititngIncident.hasChanges()) {
                if (confirm('Your have unsaved changes. Press Ok to cancel these changes. Press Cancel to continue editing')) {
                    CurrentEdititngIncident.rollback();
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            };
        }

        ko.editable(incident);
        incident.beginEdit();
        self.EditingIncident(incident);
        self.showDialog(true);
    };  

    self.SaveorUpdate = function (incident) {

        var id = this.ID,
        self.EditingIncident().commit();

        url = Incident.BASE_URL + (id ? '(' + encodeURIComponent(id) + ')' : '');

        return $.ajax(url, {
            type: id ? "MERGE" : "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON({
                Description: this.Description,
                Incident: this.Incident
            }),
            processData: false,
            contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
            headers: id ? Incident.UPDATE_HEADERS : Incident.CREATE_HEADERS,
            success: function (incident) {
                self.showDialog(false);

                self.EditingIncident(undefined);
                console.log("Record was sucessfully saved.");           
            }   
        });

... I hide some code here just to show the ko.editable functions im using.

    };
```

I created a version without requirejs in a jsfiddle to demonstrate that the same code works without requirejs. So im not quite sure what ut us that im missing. I went trough the website https://github.com/romanych/ko.editables and it mentions that its AMD compatible but cant find info on how to properly load it.

Hoping that some people are familiar with requirejs or with ko.editables. Would anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you link to the jsfiddle you created?

Comment: as ko.editables is AMD compatible, you don't need to use shims, which are there for non-AMD compatible modules. Have you opened the browser console and found logged errors? It looks like the AMD in ko.editables.js requires a module named `exports` which doesn't exist. Can you find an error in trying to load this dependency?

Comment: I went trough the console logs and i see no errors. I dont see any mention on their website about an export module but ill check this out. @hasen here is the jsfiddle without requirejs https://jsfiddle.net/4kyevk1s/8/.

Comment: Digging into the documentations I stumble on this https://github.com/romanych/ko.editables/blob/b54cf38f55894c0ca626946db119a523dcac86e7/ko.editables.js it mentions that the exports are ko.extenders.editable: ko.observable().extend({editable: true|false}); and ko.editable: ko.editable(objectWithObservables, boolean autoInit); would anyone know how to add them to requirejs config?